# Jquery mobile use pagecreate with pagecontainer

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

Part 1:
I'm changing page like this:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "newpage.html");
```

Part2:
newpage.html has the following:

```
<div data-role="page" id="news">
            <script>
                $( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#news", function( event ) {
                $('.menu-link').bigSlide();
                });
            </script>

   <a href="#menu" class="menu-link"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
</div>
```

The concept is simple: Page is loaded, menu is hidden. You click on the menu icon and a menu appears . This works if you refresh the page normally, but using pagecontainer just makes the menu appear on page load, without clicking its button , and it's loaded over the page content, so it breaks all the layout.

Why does this happen?

Comment: You're running `$('.menu-link').bigSlide();` when page is created `pagecreate`, so once `pagecreate` is fired, it executes the code.

Comment: i know, but actually $('.menu-link').bigSlide(); never fires.

Comment: @GiovanniPalerma: here is The Reference: [jQuery Mobile “Page” Events – What, Why, Where, When & How?](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/). You can even always get `e.target.id`.